# sparql does not find triple, but it exists

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, triplestore

When I'm running a SPARQL query on my virtuoso triple store like this

```
prefix base: <URI>
SELECT  ?a ?b  WHERE {
?a base:predicate ?b
}
```

It does not find my desired triple
When I am searching for it explicitly like so

```
prefix base: <URI>
SELECT  ?b WHERE {
base:subject base:predicate ?b
}
```

It gets a result.

Any idea, why this can happen?

And additionally i realized, that this one subject is not the only one. When I am running the query

```
prefix base: <URI>
SELECT COUNT(?b) as ?c  WHERE {
?a base:predicate ?b
}
```

It returns 91. But there have to be 143. This is really strange.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're using once `base:property` and once `base:predicate`, so this are obviously non-overlapping queries...

Comment: And you want to count what? The triples with predicate `base:predicate` or the distinct objects of those triples?

Comment: ah yes. property is equal to predicate. I just wanted the query to look pretty. But it is the same. And for the count: yes i want to count the triples with this predicate

Comment: I've changed `base:property` to `base:predicate` to show that these are overlapping queries

Comment: I've deleted the graph and inserted the triples again. Now it works. I still can't think about a reason for this misbehavior

Comment: It's near impossible to analyze behavior which no longer occurs. Starting points would normally include checking version(s) of binaries (i.e., Virtuoso server, any involved client tools or libraries). I also wonder about how the data was inserted, and whether there were any errors reported then.

Comment: yes you are right. To make it persistent for others who read this: The version of the virtuoso server is 07.20.3217 Build: Dec 23 2016. I've inserted the data with 143 HTTP POST requests (with multiple triples and including delete statements), all after each other. I did not consider any messages from the server. Sometimes it took 6 seconds, sometimes it took up to one minute.

Comment: _"I did not consider any messages from the server."_ Meaning that, if the server reported an error on a `POST` (such as one or more triples not inserting), you ignored such? Seems like you dug your own hole, here!

Comment: _"Seems like you dug your own hole, here!"_ This is not really the case, because as I stated: the triples exists. Fort this case, there is no need to consider messages from the server while inserting.